# Selecting multiple rows of different type from one table with given criteria, if not found select next possible row

Tags: mysql, select, join, settings

I have kind of a settings table where are columns like type, value, company, group. From that table I need to select only one row of every different type depending if my user information matches with the other columns or not.

Example I'm in company 1 and in group 1 and my settings table consist these rows:

```
+--+-----+-------+---------+-------+
|id|type | value | company | group |
+--+-----+-------+---------+-------+
|1 |1    | 50    | 1       | 1     |
|2 |1    | 70    | NULL    | NULL  |
|3 |2    | 1     | NULL    | NULL  |
|4 |2    | 99    | 1       | 1     |
|5 |2    | 999   | NULL    | 1     |
|6 |3    | 500   | NULL    | NULL  |
+--+-----+-------+---------+-------+
```

If there is setting for company or group use it, otherwise use default row(company and group are NULL). There are couple more columns like company and group.

From that table I need to select id:s 1,4 and 6, because they are settings I need in this case. Id 1 and id 4 matches with my user information, id 5 matches also, but id 4 is exact match. Id 6 matches, because there arent any closer setting of type 3.

There could be hundreds of companies and groups so I dont want to create a PHP algorithm to get correct setting value. It would be disastrous.

I tried to select rows and ordering them with company DESC, but while grouping type it wont work. I also tried to join with max(company) where company IS NOT NULL, but I got stuck and now trying to get help.

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this case!

Comment: In your example above, which record would you want for `type=2` if `id=4` had `(company, group) = (1, NULL)`?  Both `id=3` and `id=4` would match on one field, but not the other.  Does one have priority?

Comment: id 4 is exact match so it has the priority and it should be in result. Also id 4 have bigger priority than id 5 because id 5 is partial match.

Comment: Yes, but in the case where `id=4` had `(company, group) = (1, NULL)`?

Comment: id=4 is (company, group) = (1,1).

Comment: My question was, ***WHAT IF***.

Comment: oh sorry. Good question. In this case group 1 must belong to company 1. There are also other columns, where it isn't like that, but it's another thing..

Comment: So how would you resolve such collisions?  Should one column have priority over the other?

Comment: I think I have to create some validation rules when changing and creating these settigs. Thousand thanks for advice!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN (
  SELECT (
    SELECT   b.id
    FROM     my_table b
    WHERE    b.type = a.type
         AND IFNULL(b.company = 1, TRUE)
         AND IFNULL(b.group   = 1, TRUE)
    ORDER BY b.company DESC, b.group DESC
    LIMIT    1
  ) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT type FROM my_table
  ) a
)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce9aa/1/0).

---

Rewriting in a `JOIN`, which should give better performance:

```
SELECT my_table.*
FROM   my_table
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT type FROM my_table
) a ON my_table.id = (
  SELECT   b.id
  FROM     my_table b
  WHERE    b.type = a.type
       AND IFNULL(b.company = 1, TRUE)
       AND IFNULL(b.group   = 1, TRUE)
  ORDER BY b.company DESC, b.group DESC
  LIMIT    1
)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce9aa/2/0).

Comment: It seems to work. I'll test it tomorrow in big database. Thanks!!

Comment: This is what I expected! First query took too long (44sec) to get 40 different setting types from 5000 rows (maybe not realistic amount), but with JOIN, it took 0.016sec. I knew this would be possible with JOIN, but I didn't have any idea how to do it. Again milloin thanks!!

Comment: @Limitteri: Depending on your indexing, you may get better performance still by replacing `IFNULL(b.company = 1, TRUE)` with `(b.company = 1 OR b.company IS NULL)` and likewise for `b.group`.